# How to change values into a matrix?

Tags: python

I have a matrix filled with 0 values and I want to add randomly a 1 value into a and a+1 position. Then I want to use b and b+1 for the next row.. and so on.
How can I do it?

```
w, h = 10, 3
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)] 

a = random.randint(0,9)
b = random.randint(0,9)
c = random.randint(0,9)
print(a, b, c)
```

EXAMPLE:
`a = 5 b = 2 c = 1`

```
0000011000
0011000000
0110000000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please also post your attempt of writing the code yourself and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: @intedgar I wish I could solve it by myself but the for cycle I'm using change only a single value for every row: 

`for i in range(len(Matrix)):
  Matrix[i][a] = 1
  Matrix[i][a+1] = 1`

Comment: I understand that you could not solve everything by yourself. That's why you are posting the question here. But people helping you still want to see your attempt (no matter whether it's fully working) to a) see that you have tried for yourself and b) give you advice on the code that you tried and point you in a direction of how you might change it so that it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reduce the `randint` range to 8 (more generically `w-2`), or alternatively use [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) so you don't cross the edge of the row with the `+1`.

Then just loop on each row, generate the number and change that row using the number as an index:

```py
import random

w, h = 10, 3
matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

for row in matrix:
    i = random.randrange(w-1)
    print(i)
    row[i:i+2] = [1, 1]

print(*matrix, sep='\n')
```

Will give:

```
0
8
2
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In matrices in Python, you can access the row with [] and the columns with [][],

So if you want the third item in the second row, it would be [1][2] note we're starting from 0.

Getting back to your question, it would look something like this,

```
Matrix[0][a] = 1
Matrix[0][a + 1] = 1
```

And so on for the b, c but you could also use a loop.

```
random = [a, b, c]
for row in range(h):
    Matrix[row][random[row]] = 1
    Matrix[row][random[row] + 1] = 1
```

Basically what we're doing in this loop, is for each row in the matrix, which in your code is defined by h and we will look at the first row and define at the index of the random value 'a' and update it to 1.
then we'll go to 'a + 1' in the same row and also update it to 1.
And then for the next row, we'll take b and do the same thing.

Note: this would raise an error if a, b or c are 9 because as soon as you increase it by 1 you will be out the boundaries of the list which is 0 to 9